# AuthenticationManagerBuilder in SpringBoot 2.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, password-encryption

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.1.RELEASE mvc application, so in the security config I've defined this method:

```
@Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser(User
                            .withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username(DEV_USER)
                            .password(DEV_PWD)
                            .roles("ADMIN").build());
        }
```

but It seems that The method `withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` from the type User is deprecated but I don't know which I have to use instead,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Spring Framework Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#withDefaultPasswordEncoder--)

```
@Deprecated
public static User.UserBuilder withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
```

> Deprecated. Using this method is not considered safe for production,
>   but is acceptable for demos and getting started. For production
>   purposes, ensure the password is encoded externally. See the method
>   Javadoc for additional details.
>
> WARNING: This method is considered unsafe for production and is only
>   intended for sample applications.

```
UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
     .username("user")
     .password("password")
     .roles("USER")
     .build();
 // outputs {bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
 System.out.println(user.getPassword());
```

> This is not safe for production (it is intended for getting started
>   experience) because the password "password" is compiled into the
>   source code and then is included in memory at the time of creation.
>   This means there are still ways to recover the plain text password
>   making it unsafe. It does provide a slight improvement to using plain
>   text passwords since the UserDetails password is securely hashed. This
>   means if the UserDetails password is accidentally exposed, the
>   password is securely stored. In a production setting, it is
>   recommended to hash the password ahead of time. For example:

```
PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
 // outputs {bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
 // remember the password that is printed out and use in the next step
 System.out.println(encoder.encode("password"));



UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
     .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG")
     .roles("USER")
     .build();
```

Returns:
    a UserBuilder that automatically encodes the password with the default PasswordEncoder

To answer your question, you can do :

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername(DEV_USER)
                 .password(encoder.encode(DEV_PWD))
                 .roles("ADMIN")
                 .build();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userDetails);
    }
```